# Struggle to identify the cause of this SecurityException error (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, exception, xamarin.android

Google PlayStore reports this issue several times for my Xamarin app. Sadly, I don't know the users and can not ask them what they did.
In this case, I have no clue where to look for the issue, as it seems to happen in code that is not under my control?

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2088)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2056)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:188)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:151)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile (ContentProviderNative.java:705)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor (ContentResolver.java:1694)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor (ContentResolver.java:1510)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream (ContentResolver.java:1194)
  at crc64f4b801cc44c5ec3d.MainActivity.n_onStart (Native Method)
  at crc64f4b801cc44c5ec3d.MainActivity.onStart (MainActivity.java:49)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1433)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:7978)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3580)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:221)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:201)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:173)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2216)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

The last part of code I seem to have in control here is MainActivity.onStart and there below in the flow the function GetRFileDataAsync(). It works for hundreds of people, but obviously not for all. I found one usage of openInputStream() in this function:

```
protected override async Task<byte[]> GetRFileDataAsync()
        {
            byte[] byteArray = null;
            var intent = _mainActivity.Intent;
            bool isSend = intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend;
            var uri = isSend
                ? intent.ClipData.GetItemAt(0).Uri
                : intent.Data;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(uri != null);

            using (var inputStream = _mainActivity.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri))
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await inputStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return byteArray;
        }
```

This is the only use of openInputStream() in the whole project. But how to catch this problem correctly (or better make it not happen at all)?

Comment: You need to set `android:exported="true"`  in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Hello. Can you please explain what this does and how this fixes the issue? I found the explanation here, but I do not see the link to my crash? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element

My app uses intent filters, so the default should be "true" anyway (due to the above documentation)?

Comment: Did you have a try ?

Comment: How to try, as it only happens at unknown customers? If I change something, I have to trigger the beta testers. And then, if all is good, I have to release for public. And then I have to wait if it still happens. Thus, I don't want to do experiments. Better for me to understand and then do qualified changes. Of course, as TRUE is the default, I will set this value for the next release. But I do not expect it to change something (as it is the default with intent filters anyway).

Comment: I'm not sure where to set this value. For <provider>? For the <activity> or for the <receiver> parts?

Comment: For the <activity> .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Okay, I added that flag in MainActivity.cs for the activity. So keep fingers crossed... Thank you for your tips.